# Replace line before match using Sed

Tags: sed, replace

I want to replace line before match using `sed`

Input file

```
.AAA(AAA),
.BBB(BBB));
.AAA(AAA),
.CCC(CCC),
.BBB(BBB));
.AAA(AAA),
.DDD(DDD),
.BBB(BBB));
```

I can replace  the matching line `.BBB(BBB));`

but don't know how to replace the line before match to get this output

```
.AAA(AAA));
.BBB(BBB));
.AAA(AAA),
.CCC(CCC));
.BBB(BBB));
.AAA(AAA),
.DDD(DDD));
.BBB(BBB));
```

Comment: are those `, \n` presented as raw text in your file?

Comment: \n not in  my file, i just want to present a newline

Comment: @黃明明 I've edited the question accordingly... you'll have to add your own efforts to solve the problem to get help on SO

Answer (score 4):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'N;s/,\(\s*\n\.BBB\)/);\1/;P;D' file
```

Read two lines into the pattern space and substitute on match, replacing the previous `,` by `);`.

P.S. I presume that the `\n` are suppose to represent a newline separating each line.

EDIT:

The command `P` prints upto and including any newline `\n` in the pattern space. If there is no newline in the pattern, then the whole of the pattern is printed and newline appended.

The command 'D' deletes upto and including any newline `\n` in the pattern space. If there is a newline in the pattern space before the command is executed then afterwards, if the pattern space is not empty, new line is not read into the pattern space and execution of sed commands continues as if a new line has been read into the patten space. If the pattern space is empty, normal processing is resumed with the pattern space being filled by the next line from file being read (minus its newline).

Comment: You get the close examination of the question award.  The title is misleading-- if your code here is right, the OP only wanted to replace the commas with semicolons.

Comment: thanks a lot. could you please explain why add `;P;D` ... i try some case without `;P;D` also can give the right result, but some case can't.

Comment: this script works globally instead of just 1 line. perfect.

Answer (score 1):

`sed -n -e '1h;1n;/BBB/h;//!{x;p};$p' file`

- `sed -n` don't print unless `p` command is used
- `1h;1n;` save the first line in the hold space and move to line 2
- `/BBB/h` save lines matching BBB in the hold space.  This discards the previous line without printing it.
- `//!{x;p}` for lines not matching BBB (`//` is previous match pattern), exchange with the hold space and print.  This saves the current line and prints the previous.
- `$p` always print the last line

Input:

```
.AAA(AAA), 
.BBB(BBB)); 
.AAA(AAA), 
.CCC(CCC), 
.BBB(BBB)); 
.AAA(AAA), 
.DDD(DDD), 
.BBB(BBB));
```

Output:

```
.BBB(BBB)); 
.AAA(AAA), 
.BBB(BBB)); 
.AAA(AAA), 
.BBB(BBB));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `awk` rather than `sed`:

```
awk 'NR>1&&!/BBB/{print b}{b=$0}END{print b}' a.txt
```

Explanation:

I'm using `b` to buffer the previous line. Starting from line 2 I check if the current line does not match `BBB` and print `b` in that case.

```
NR>1&&!/BBB/{print b}
```

I store every line in `b` using this:

```
{b=$0}
```

Once the last line has been reached we print `b`:

```
END{print b}
```

Comment: The `sed` version of this is just different obtuse syntax.

Comment: Well, I personally like going crazy with `sed`, but if you do so in a professional (company) environment you'll end up with code nobody can  modify and maintain or even understand. Also the `sed` stuff can get endlessly complicated if the use case just changes a little bit. I recommend `awk`, if not a programming language which the OP already knows.